# Detecting Ruby mixin being included

Tags: ruby, dynamic

I have a question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175496/executing-a-mixin-method-at-the-end-of-a-class-definition).  I'm writing an app that has an addon system.  There's an Addon mixin module, which detects when it's included and registers the new addon automatically:

```
module Addon
  def self.included(receiver)
     addon = receiver.new   # Create an instance of the addon
     (snip)                 # Other stuff to register the addon 
     addon.on_register      # Tell the instance it was registered
  end
end
```

Here is an example of how the mixin would be used:

```
class MyAddon
  def on_register
    puts "My addon was registered"
  end
  include Addon  # ** note that this is at the end of the class **
end
```

As noted above, this implementation requires that the include be at the bottom of the class.  Otherwise on_register isn't defined at the time that self.included gets called.

My concern is that an addon developer might accidentally put the include at the top, causing the addon not to work.   Or that there might be a derived class or something that would extend the MyAddon class after it was already included.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After distilling the other answers and some other info I found, I wanted to document the answer that ended up working for me.

As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215352/callback-when-a-class-is-loaded) explains, you can't detect at include() time when a class is "done" being defined.  So, relying on the 'included' callback to create the objects was not a very robust solution.

The solution instead was to discover all of the addons and instantiate them **after** everything had been loaded.   The only constraint placed on addon developers was that their code had to share a common top-level module namespace.

I still don't know if this is the *best* way to do it, but it definitely works better than what I started with.

Here is the code that searches the module for addons.  It starts at a passed-in namespace and searches recursively for classes that include the addon class:

```
def find_and_instantiate(mod, addons)
   consts = mod.constants
   consts.each do |c|
     sym = mod.const_get(c)
     if (sym.class == Module)
       find_and_instantiate(sym, addons)
     else
       if (sym.class == Class && sym.include?(Addon))
         addons << sym.new(@container)            
       end
     end        
   end
 end
```

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution and that you understood that instantiation in the `included` hook was not a very robust solution. I'm so glad that I give you +1, although on SO, answering one's own questions is generally done mostly by newbies.

Comment: I appreciate your +1 and your input.  I was going off the advice` of [Jeff Atwood](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/): "...It is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is **explicitly encouraged**."   Granted, that was from last year and perhaps things have changed since then.

Comment: The two propositions are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky, your tone is a bit aggressive here... I think it's perfectly legal to answer your own questions, especially in cases when you're working on a corner case where the answer isn't easily googlable.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can come up with is to notify the user of your module that it needs to be included after the `#on_register` method has been declared:

```
module Addon
  def self.included(receiver)
        raise "include #{self.name} after the #on_register method is defined" unless receiver.method_defined? :on_register
        receiver.new.send(:on_register)
  end
end
```

This is less than ideal but it will prevent aggravating mistakes until you discover a better way of doing this.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but I have to hand this to you. So you want to hear your code is clever, pal. Yes, it is, it is too clever. But if you want to be concerned about other developers, you will have to stop being clever and start being normal.

Ruby is an OO language. The basis of OOP is that I define my object structure and their methods first, and then, when everything is defined, I instantiate my world ideally with a single call MyApp.new. That way, it does not matter what I have defined first. 'include' calls serve to establish the module inheritance hierarchy, nothing else.

But no, you do not want to do OOP. You want to abuse the `included` hook and instantiate receiver (!) in it, and call its instance methods. That's what they call obfuscated code. In other words, you go from OOP back to the old good `goto` style directive programming. Ruby allows you to obfuscate, not to limit your abilities, but with great power great responsibility, you yourself must exercise moderation.

You will yoursef have to refactor your code to make it normal. We cannot do that for you, because we don't know what do you want to achieve. Who knows, maybe you idea is worthy of a genius. Too bad we don't know it from your question. Some addon system you have. I'm asking you: Do you need it? Isn't good old mixin system good enough for you? Are you sure you are not programming Java in Ruby? And, then, is your app going to be greater than Rails? If yes, go ahead with the addon system. If not – stop playing around and invest your time in writing the algos that actually do what your app is suppose to do rather than creating inextricable addon systems in advance. If you are working in a company - which I doubt - make sure you let your boss read this.

Comment: No, I'm not expecting this is going to be the accepted answer today. But maybe in 3 months, outside SO, you will see the light :-)

Comment: The addon system is central to the app, and the dynamic features of Ruby make it an ideal solution.  If there's a better way to load(myaddon.rb), detect the MyAddon class and load it dynamically -- I'd love to hear it.  Otherwise, your answer is unhelpful, and a bit insulting.

Comment: The [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175496) you refer to is less harmful, because it only reflects on the receiver. By _instantiating_ the receiver in `included`, you are creating a lot of needless constraints for the receiver writer. Totally concrete question is: Must you instantiate the reciever in the `include` call? More general question would be, what does your app do? I do not believe you have to go through this to make it work.

Comment: No, it does not need to instantiate the receiver in the include.  I have an addon manager that scans an addons directory for *.rb files, calls load() on each of them, and then somehow needs to instantiate all the addon classes.  If there's a better way to do it, I'm all for it.

Comment: Put this way, it sounds more normal. I would simply write a script that gets a list of *.rb files in your directory (eg. 'my_addon.rb', 'his_addon.rb', 'her_addon.rb'), extracts the file names, loads them all, and then for each file name then calls `new` method, like `MyAddon.new; HisAddon.new, HerAddon.new`. I would make it a requirement for addon writers that their file names are in snake case the same as their class names in camel case (reasonable and intuitive CoC requirement) and I would make it the responsibility of addon classes to integrate themselves in the object society of your app.